# python - unittesting super() calls

Tags: python, python-unittest

```
class A(object):

    def get_value(self):
        return "foo"


class B(A):

    def get_value(self):
        value = super(B, self).get_value()
        value + "bar"
        return value
```

Given the above classes, when I wanted to write a testsuite for the `B()` class, how do I go about mocking that `super()` call to `A()`'s `get_value()` method? The pseudo-ish code for what I want would be:

```
class BTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.b = B()

    def test_get_value(self):
        # This won't work, attribute error- "super" object has
        # no attribute get_value
        super(B, self.b).get_value = Mock()
        super(B, self.b).get_value.assert_called_once_with()
```

but obviously that won't work. But I'm wondering whether there is a way to test for the call, and if patching is the way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

`super(type[, object-or-type])`
Return a **proxy object** that **delegates method calls** to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that used by getattr() except that the type itself is skipped.
<...>

There are two typical use cases for super.

- In a class hierarchy with single inheritance, super can be used to refer to parent classes without naming them explicitly, thus making the code more maintainable. <...>
- The second use case is to support cooperative multiple inheritance in a dynamic execution environment. <...>

__

In other words, `super` is a class for getting methods and properties, and **not** for setting them.

If You want to monkey-patch something, use instances or classes directly:

```
class A(object): ...
class B(A): ...
b = B()

super(B, b).get_value = Something()  # no
b.get_value = Something()  # ok
B.get_value = Something()  # ok
A.get_value = Something()  # ok
```

Comment: Like all good answers, painfully obvious once explained clearly :) thanks.