# unittesting: patching an objects __base__

Tags: python, python-unittest

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539769/python-unittesting-super-calls), I attempted to patch class `A()` with `Mock()` so that when `B()` was initialised, the Mock was used as a base e.g.:

```
class A(object): ...
class B(A): ...

def setUp(self):
    with patch('A', new_callable=Mock) as MockObject:
        self.b = B()
        self.b.__class__.__base__ = MockOjbect
```

Which doesn't work because **base** is read only. What's the correct way to go about doing this?

update:

```
>>> from mock import Mock
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     pass
... 
>>> b.__class__.__bases__ = (Mock, )
>>> b.__class__.__bases__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/envs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 656, in __getattr__
    elif self._mock_methods is not None:
  File "/opt/envs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 655, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _mock_methods
```

To be clear, I'm not convinced this is the best way to achieve what I want to do, I'm half hoping someone else will come up with another way.

Comment: Your original question was: "How do I patch an object's __bases__ ?". I'm not sure what you want to do anymore and believe my answer is now invalid for your follow up. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `__bases__` which is a `tuple`.

Corrected version:

```
class A(object): ...
class B(A): ...

def setUp(self):
    with patch('A', new_callable=Mock) as MockObject:
        self.b = B()
        self.b.__class__.__bases__ = (MockOjbect,)
```

See:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> Foo.__class__.__bases__
(<type 'object'>,)
```

`tuple`'s are **immutable** but the `__bases__` attribute is most certainly not read-only.

Comment: Thanks, although now `TypeError: B.__bases__ must be tuple of old- or new-style classes, not 'Mock'` is the barrier to entry...

Comment: That is entirely a different problem altogether! Best you ask another question or try to figure out the ``TypeError`` on your own :) It is more or less fairly self explanatory.

Comment: Would disagree on the separate question part, as I still technically don't have a working answer to this one :)

Comment: Well it wasn't part of your original problem :) However as a hint, your tuple of bases **must** be classes.

Comment: True, that part I worked out however :) see the update